# Python - why is it not reading my variables?

Tags: python, variables, function

I'm a python newbie and I don't understand why it won't read my IP and ADDR variables in the function dns.zone.query(IP, ADDR)???

```
import dns.query
import dns.zone
import sys

IP = sys.stdin.readline()
ADDR = sys.stdin.readline()


z = dns.zone.from_xfr(dns.query.xfr(IP , ADDR))
names = z.nodes.keys()
names.sort()
for n in names:
    print z[n].to_text(n)
```

It works when I pass an actual IP and Domain, but not with the variables... I don't get what's wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error message? Have you tried debugging it to see on which line it goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with:

```
IP = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
ADDR = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
```

Add some prints after the variables to debug it:

```
print '_%s_' % IP
print '_%s_' % ADDR
```

Answer (score 6):

`readline()` will include a trailing newline. You can use `sys.stdin.readline().strip()`

Answer (score 2):

Try `sys.stdin.readline().strip()`.  You need to remove the newlines.